# Eclipse ARM mbed cannot move location counter backward error

Tags: eclipse, ld, mbed

while I was following this tutorial 

https://developer.mbed.org/cookbook/eclipse-for-building-and-debugging 
I run on a error building the project on Eclipse (I followed all the steps untill the first build project at which point I received the following error):

```
../../external/mbed/libraries/mbed/targets/cmsis/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC11UXX/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/TARGET_LPC11U24_401/LPC11U24.ld:50 cannot move location counter backwards (from 00000238 to 00000200) collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [LPC11U24/FileTest.elf] Error 1
```

Since ld is involved I think the problem is related to the linker but I have no clue what to do and where to look at. I'm working in Debian 32 bit and Eclipse LUNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I selected the wrong toolchain: linux gcc instead of cross gcc.